# Confusing output in multithreading shows deadlock?

Tags: java, multithreading

I just compiled and run this program of java but the output is unpleasant.
I don't know why the threads are in deadlock situation.
Can anyone help me to understand the output of the program.

```
class A {
synchronized void foo(B b) {
    String name=Thread.currentThread().getName();
    System.out.println(name+"entered A.foo");

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch(Exception e) {}
    System.out.println(name+"trying to call B.last()");
    b.last();
}
synchronized void last() {
    System.out.println("inside A.last");
}
}

class B {
synchronized void bar(A a) {
    String name=Thread.currentThread().getName();
    System.out.println(name+"entered B.bar");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("b interrupted");
    }
    System.out.println(name+"trying to call A.last()");
    a.last();
}
synchronized void last() {
    System.out.println("inside A.last");
}
}

class DeadLock implements Runnable {
A a=new A();
B b=new B();
DeadLock() {
    Thread.currentThread().setName("mainthread");
    Thread t=new Thread(this,"racingthread");
    t.start();
    a.foo(b);
    System.out.println("back in main thread");
}
public void run() {
    b.bar(a);
    System.out.println("back in other theread");
}
public static void main(String...d) {
    new DeadLock();
}
}
```

**the output on my computer is**

```
mainthreadentered A.foo

racingthreadentered B.bar

mainthreadtrying to call B.last()

racingthreadtrying to call A.last()
```

Comment: Is this homework?  Please add the tag if so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a classic deadlock.

- `A.foo()` locks `a` and calls `b.last()` which attempts to lock `b`
- `B.bar()` locks `b1` and calls `a.last()` which attempts to lock `a`

Neither can proceed because each needs the lock of the other.

> I don't know why the threads are in deadlock situation.

Because that is what your program is designed to do.

---

Given you don't need any of the locks, the simplest solution is to remove all the `synchronized` keywords.

Comment: i'm confused calling a method through object ref lock the object?as in calling A.foo()

Comment: ya removing synchroziation will help to run all the methods but what happened as i removed all the synchronization keyword from the method

Comment: @krishna Chandra: Calling a `synchronized` method on an object will attempt to acquire the lock on that object.

Answer (score 0):

As object b is locked on `bar()` and `a` on `foo()`, so when you call `last()` each function is waiting for the other to release the lock. that is causing the deadlock

Answer (score 0):

Looks like homework.  But I'd say the answer is around the fact you setup another thread inside the constructor of deadlock().

Both threads will race and could get locked on one of the synchronised methods because you are using a timer to bring them into line.  Is my guess without running it.

Also class names should be upper case.

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution for Deadlock. Programmer has to take care and code in such a way that deadlock should not occur.